Tauri app sidecar that requires another executable results in Error: Cannot find module
I have a Tauri app sidecar written in Node.js, I use pkg to package the node app into an executable, the name of the sidecar is server-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe.
I am able to use @tauri-apps/api/shell in the client side and execute the sidecar:
import { Command } from '@tauri-apps/api/shell';
const command = Command.sidecar('bin/server');
console.log(command)
command.on('close', data => {
    console.log(`command finished with code ${data.code} and signal ${data.signal}`)
});
const output = await command.execute();
console.log(" ~ output:", output)

However, one of the packages I am using inside the node app (the sidecar) requires 3rd party executable and files, so when I am executing the command I am facing a node.js Error: Cannot find module 'C:\snapshot\dist/build/Release... error.
When I am executing server-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe directly on my PC it works fine and there is no problem with requiring the 3rd party files.
tauri.conf.json:
{
    "$schema": "../../../node_modules/@tauri-apps/cli/schema.json",
    "build": {
        "beforeBuildCommand": "yarn build:browser",
        "beforeDevCommand": "yarn dev:browser",
        "devPath": "http://localhost:4000",
        "distDir": "../dist"
    },
    "package": {
        "productName": "desktop-app",
        "version": "0.1.0"
    },
    "tauri": {
        "allowlist": {
            "all": false,
            "shell": {
                "execute": true,
                "sidecar": true,
                "scope": [{ "name": "bin/server", "sidecar": true }] // this is important
            }
        },
        "bundle": {
            "active": true,
            "category": "DeveloperTool",
            "copyright": "",
            "deb": {
                "depends": []
            },
            "externalBin": ["bin/server"], // this is important
            "icon": [
                "icons/32x32.png",
                "icons/128x128.png",
                "icons/128x128@2x.png",
                "icons/icon.icns",
                "icons/icon.ico"
            ],
            "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",
            "longDescription": "",
            "macOS": {
                "entitlements": null,
                "exceptionDomain": "",
                "frameworks": [],
                "providerShortName": null,
                "signingIdentity": null
            },
            "shortDescription": "",
            "targets": "all",
            "windows": {
                "certificateThumbprint": null,
                "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
                "timestampUrl": ""
            }
        },
        "security": {
            "csp": null
        },
        "updater": {
            "active": false
        },
        "windows": [
            {
                "fullscreen": false,
                "height": 600,
                "resizable": true,
                "title": "Desktop Server",
                "width": 800
            }
        ]
    }
}


Folder structure:
desktop-app/
├─src/
│　├─index.html
│　├─index.js
│　└─...
└─src-tauri/
　　├─bin/
　　│　├─build/
　　│　│　└─Releases/
　　│　│　　　├─3rd-party-executable
　　│　│　　　├─3rd-party-file
　　│　│　　　└─...
　　│　└─server-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe
　　├─src/
　　├─target/
　　├─tauri.conf.json
　　└─...


Are you still struggling with this? Basically, you have to add the external binaries as resources in the tauri conf so they get bundled in the final exe and installed with the main app / sidecar.
